Identifying this shrub?
Can anyone help me identify this plant.


Locally they call it "Logotipo", but I can't find the English name for it.
Appreciate the assistance.

Where is "locally"?

Arequipa, Peru.

An image search yields Stoebe and Maireana as (to my eyes) the most likely candidates. Not sure though.

The shrub in the image is likely to be Santolina chamaecyparissus, commonly known as cotton lavender or gray santolina. It is characterized by its silvery-gray foliage and is often used in gardens for its aromatic leaves and ornamental appearance.

It does indeed have an aroma and is used to define the border between the lawn and flower bed. I believe you are correct. Thanks.
